# Unable to extract required field from JSON text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract a specific field "`Engineering Lead`" and its corresponding value  from the JSON text but however, when tried to extract it directly from the JSON, it is throwing the key error as shown in the `code1` . Since it is not working, i have decided to loop it to fetch the key `Engineering Lead` and it is value but it still throwing the same error. any help would be aprreciated.

json text:

```
{'expand': 'renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations', 'id': '11659640', 'self': '/rest/api/2/issue/11659640', 'key': 'TOOLSTEST-2651', 'fields': {'description': 'h2. Main\r\n * *:*\r\n * *Application ISO:*\xa0Tony Zeinoun\r\n * *Engineering Lead:*\xa0Peter james\r\n * *Application Architect:*\xa0John david\r\n * *Divisional Architect:*\xa0Robert denuvit'}}
```

code 1:

```
 engLeadDetails = data_load['fields']['* \*Engineering Lead']
```

Code 2:

```
engLeadDetails = data_load['fields']
    for k,v in engLeadDetails.items():
        if (k == '* \*Engineering Lead'):
            print (v)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/peter/abc.py", line 32, in <module>
    engLeadDetails = data_load['fields']['* *Engineering Lead']
KeyError: '* *Engineering Lead'
```

Comment: Did you try printing the dictionary?

Comment: The error is expected. * \*Engineering Lead' is a string of description. It is not a key. Check better your dictionary and you will see it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

I think python can't find such key because of some missing quotes. Please check the json text once more. It seems like `* *Engineering Lead` is currently a part of a bigger string, but not a key (due to missing quotes).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the JSON string description into a dictionary by splitting on `\r\n` sequence then break the role and name into key/values and add to a dictionary.

The expression `\W*` in regexp below will strip off the non-alphanumeric prefix off the roles and names; e.g., "** *Application ISO*" => "*Application ISO*", etc.

Try something like this:

```python
data = {}
for s in data_load['fields']['description'].split('\r\n'):
    if m := re.search(r'^\W*(.*?):\W*(.+)', s):
        if label := m.group(1):
            data[label] = m.group(2)
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Application ISO': 'Tony Zeinoun', 'Engineering Lead': 'Peter james', 'Application Architect': 'John david', 'Divisional Architect': 'Robert denuvit'}
```

Then can grab a particular role/person out:

```
print(">>", data.get("Engineering Lead"))
```

Outputs:

```
>> Peter james
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. On the testing the code, i realized that output is  Peter james\xa0 .  But in the json text, none of the text contains \xa0 but it is still being added to the output.

Comment: @peter The posted sample JSON shows "*Engineering Lead:*\xa0Peter james\r\n" and when parsed extracts just "Peter james" and strips any non-word characters before the name.

Answer (score 0):

KeyError means that the key `* \*Engineering Lead` doesn't exist in the dictionary.

It appears the delimiter of the description (where your EngLead is stored) is \r\n.

Using this we can split the description to get each role.

```py
job_details = data_load["fields"]["description"]
```

Removing arbitrary strings, this leaves us with

```
job_details = [
 "* *Application ISO:* Tony Zeinoun",       
 "* *Engineering Lead:* Peter james",       
 "* *Application Architect:* John david", 
 "* *Divisional Architect:* Robert denuvit",
]
```

I am assuming you want the name of the person in each position.

Now we remove arbitrary characters from each string.

```py
job_dict = {}
for s in job_details:
    s = s.replace("*","").strip()
    job, person = s.split(":")
    job_dict[job] = person.strip()
```

`job_dict` is now clean, with easy key access to each job.

Resultant Dict:

```json
{ 
  'Application Architect': 'John david',   
  'Application ISO': 'Tony Zeinoun',       
  'Divisional Architect': 'Robert denuvit',
  'Engineering Lead': 'Peter james'
}
```

```
print(job_dict["Engineering Lead"])  # Peter james
```